# Why am I getting compilation errors in a new MVC4 project?

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I haven't been able to find an answer to this and have been scouring the internet all weekend, so I was hoping maybe you could help me out with this.

When using Visual Studio 2012, I create a new MVC4 Web Application Project and get some compilation errors.

Here is my problem:

1. I create a new MVC4 Web Application using Visual Studio 2012, I select Internet Application and set it to use RAZOR Engine.
2. I go to Application Properties and under the Application Tab I change Target Framework from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Framework 4.
3. The build produces the following errors:

   > Error 1   The type name 'TableAttribute' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.   c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 21  6   MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 2   The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 21  6   MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 3   The type or namespace name 'DatabaseGeneratedAttributeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 25  10  MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 4   The type name 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.   c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 25  10  MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 5   The type or namespace name 'CompareAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 54  10  MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 6   The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 54  10  MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 7   The type or namespace name 'CompareAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 87  10  MvcApplication1
   >
   > Error 8   The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\saad\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Models\AccountModels.cs 87  10  MvcApplication1

Comment: any news about this ?

Answer (score 26):

Simply Reinstall EntityFramework:

1. Go to Package Manager Console
2. Uninstall-Package entityframework
3. Install-Package entityframework

that is it the error should go away!

Comment: Beware: Package manager console commands appear to be case sensitive or picky about spacing. This answer initially failed for me until I typed it exactly as shown.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, it is not a problem of MVC4 template project but of changing the target .Net Framework.

When  you create a new MVC4 project in VS2012, it will (by default) reference .Net 4.5. All files are generated based upon this version. The AccountModel use new attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` (`TableAttribute`, `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`, ...

Retargetting the framework version only change references and does not affect source code : attributes from 4.5 framework will not be removed.

If you want a MVC4 projet with .Net 4.0, you could :

- Removed .net 4.5 attributes from AccountModel
- Remove AccountMode if it is not require
- Select .NET 4.0 in the Create a New Project Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

The Uninstall-Package entityframework / Install-Package entityframework solution didn't work for me. Instead I had to open the .csproj file in notepad and do a find and replace "net40" to "net45" to force it to load the .net 4.5 version of all the packages. This made the correct version of EntityFramework load as well.